# undefined method `embeded_in'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

Here are logs

```
:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-08-23T23:55:55+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished

2011-08-23T23:55:58+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `thin -p 14541 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`

2011-08-23T23:56:04+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/models/article.rb:7:in `<class:Article>': undefined method `embeded_in' for Article:Class (NoMethodError)

2011-08-23T23:56:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/app/models/article.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'

2011-08-23T23:56:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'

2011-08-23T23:56:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'

2011-08-23T23:56:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:227:in `load_dependency'

2011-08-23T23:56:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'

2011-08-23T23:56:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:300:in `depend_on'

2011-08-23T23:56:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:346:in `require_or_load'

2011-08-23T23:56:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:138:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'

2011-08-23T23:56:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:216:in `require_dependency'

2011-08-23T23:56:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:137:in `each'

2011-08-23T23:56:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:137:in `block in eager_load!'

2011-08-23T23:56:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:135:in `each'

2011-08-23T23:56:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:135:in `eager_load!'

2011-08-23T23:56:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:108:in `eager_load!'

2011-08-23T23:56:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:41:in `block in <module:Finisher>'

2011-08-23T23:56:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'

2011-08-23T23:56:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'

2011-08-23T23:56:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `block in run_initializers'

2011-08-23T23:56:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'

2011-08-23T23:56:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'

2011-08-23T23:56:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'

2011-08-23T23:56:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'

2011-08-23T23:56:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'

2011-08-23T23:56:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'

2011-08-23T23:56:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'

2011-08-23T23:56:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:3:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'

2011-08-23T23:56:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:23:in `eval'

2011-08-23T23:56:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:23:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'

2011-08-23T23:56:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'

2011-08-23T23:56:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'

2011-08-23T23:56:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:63:in `new'

2011-08-23T23:56:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:63:in `map'

2011-08-23T23:56:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:18:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
```

Article model

```
class Article

include Mongoid::Document

field :title, :type => String

field :text, :type => String

field :image, :type => String


embeded_in :game

end
```

I am using mongoid 2.1.9 gem , Any idea why its raising issue at embeds_in ?

Comment: `embeded_in` => `embedded_in`

Answer (score 2):

Try to change `embeded_in` to `embedded_in`